# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() on Android doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to execute some commands from android app:

```
String[] cmd = {"su","-c","cat /storage/sdcard0/test.dat > /dev/ttyGS1"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();
```

Nothing happens after executing this but when I the same command works on adb shell without any problem.

```
su -c cat /storage/sdcard0/test.dat > /dev/ttyGS1
```

Does anyone know where I can try to find reason for this problem?

Comment: Why do you need `su -c`? Just run `cat` as your current user...

Comment: I tried cat as current user but effect is the same. Nothing happens. I just read somewhere to try with su but also without any luck. Yes phone is rooted

Comment: How about `{"cat", "/storage/sdcard0/test.dat > /dev/ttyGS1"}`?

Comment: Or, there is probably something about output redirection that can't be done from Java like that

Comment: @cricket_007 Because it's the shell (`sh`, `bash`, ...) that does pipe/redirect, not the OS, see duplicate link. Same for Windows (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: @Andreas I understand that. There is "Nothing happens" in the Java code, sure

Comment: I read the duplicate link before asking this question but duplicate link says that "sh", "-c", "/storage/sdcard0/test.dat > /dev/ttyGS1" But it doesnt work also.

Comment: @cricket_007 If output is not redirected to file, which it won't be without shell, then all output is sent to Java. If that output exceeds the buffer capacity, the `cat` command will stop to wait for buffer to be emptied, but Java program doesn't read output, so deadlock ensues.

Comment: @Andreas Could you help how to make this pipe in my example. If I understand correctly I need to stream output from cat into serial port /dev/ttyGS1 but I have no idea how to make it happen.